# Sniff traffic coming from one particular application?

Tags: windows, wireshark, sniffing

Basically I'd like to sniff HTTP requests made by an .exe on Windows. I tried using wireshark, but it's somewhat unhandy since it sniffs all traffic on the interface. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture traffic for specific application](http://superuser.com/questions/88444/capture-traffic-for-specific-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [SocketSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html); it lets you examine connection activity for a specified program.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer procmon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx, and you get much more of what the app is doing as well.

Comment: Ok, I can see processes with it, but how do I see tcp queries?? Like, GET/POST requests, headers, etc. I filtered it by "TCP Send" and by "TCP Receive" but by opening each of that, I can only see date, PID, parent PID, timestamps when it ended, call stack, probably anything possible except the content itself! (paths, headers, arguments/values, like on a screenshot in accepted answer)

Comment: @JerryGreen you might want to use a tool more suited for the job, maybe procmon in addition to Wireshark maybe? You can see IP:Port info in procmon, and filter Wireshark traffic based on that, but Wireshark will give you a much better picture of what the traffic looks like imho.