# Capturing network traffic of a single Application/Tab

Tags: network-adapter, wireshark, sniffing, network-traffic

I often come across a situation where I have to analyze external communication of a Mobile or Desktop Application or even a paritcular tab of a browser. I sniff traffic usually with wireshark but at any particular moment many other applications/services are also using NIC even I try to minimize the communication by disabling them (system level communication etc).

So while collecting traffic, I am never sure whether these packets are solely sent by target application/web visit. To overcome this I have to collect traffic for a number of times to get a fairly closer hint but that is also not reliable way. [possible duplicate to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/523431/sniff-traffic-coming-from-one-particular-application) question but the suggested answer seems to workable for 32 bit programs only and not state of the art.

Is there any sophisticated solution for all use cases (mobile,desktop applications and browsing a website)?

Thanks in advance.