# Getting the on screen keyboard to pop up from the bottom when focus is in text field in Windows 10 (like mobile)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, tablet

I have a Windows 10 tablet (not the Windows 10 Phone Insider Build).  One of the issue I've had with it lately is getting to act like Windows 10 Phone Insider Build.   On Windows 10 Mobile, when you focus on a text field, the keyboard pops up from the bottom, much like Android phones and iPhones.

However, on Windows 10, nothing of the sort happens, as it is not the mobile OS.  Thus, on the tablet, without a keyboard, I must find the program under Windows Ease of Access in the Programs List.

Is there a way to have a virtual keyboard much like the mobile OSs pop up when highlighting/focusing on a text field in Windows 10 for desktops?

Comment: Do you have a little keyboard button on the taskbar next to the notification area? It should be there by default. Additionally, it should pop-up on focus of typeable fields (in some programs, including the built-in ones) by default.

Comment: Nothing pops up, and there's no keyboard icon.  The keyboard icon only shows up when I manually launch the On-Screen Keyboard from the programs list, and it never pops up on focus of any typeable fields (tried using password fields for connecting to wifi, or start menu search, etc.)

Comment: Do you have an on-screen keyboard option when you right-click the taskbar? https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/3fo7fl/helpon_screen_keyboard_disappeared_after_windows/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in programs, and programs that correctly support touch on Windows 10, should pop up the keyboard automatically. Programs that do not support touch won't do so.

You might need to go to Settings => Devices => Typing and enable the "Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there's no keyboard attached to your device" option ([source](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/make-windows-10-show-touch-keyboard-automatically)). This might also be called "Show the touch keyboard or handwriting panel when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached" on recent builds.

[image: auto-shot option screenshot]

---

Additionally, you should have a keyboard button on the taskbar, between the notification area and the clock. This provides an easy way to bring up the keyboard for programs that don't auto-show it.

If the button is not visible, right-click on the taskbar (long-tap for touch) and select the "Show touch keyboard button" option.

[image: Screenshot of button]

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 have so many bugs. Sometimes, the only real solution is a third party software solution.

For your situation, I recommend a software named [Tabtip On-Demand](http://www.chessware.ch/tabtipod), a good piece of software.

Here's an overview from their own site:

> “Tabtip On-Demand is a great tool for mobile users with Tablet PC which adds the missing keyboard « on-demand » functionality to the Windows input panel. It is also able to scroll web pages and push input fields into view, thus the text are typing is never hidden behind the keyboard. Tabtip On-Demand also makes the keyboard available by mouse click (optional) on the desktop as well as in the Modern UI (Windows 8 and above).”

[image: this is what Tabtip looks like.]

And now I use it to type this answer.

Personally, I think it is useful, you can forget it once you start it. You can always make setting by clicking its icon at right menu corner. It has two mode, tabtip mode and osk mode. However, it cannot always pop up in some special text field (for example, text field of Google), then you have to start keyboard manually.

P.S It only costs $1.5, a cheap choice.)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a newbie sorry for that :(  ,I have improved  it just now.@bertieb